# ImmutableJS - How to sort a date in descendent order

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, date, immutable.js

I have this function that sorts dates in ascendent order (from the first date to the last date), I'm using immutableJS https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/sortBy:

```
export const OrderedMapSelector = (state) => {
  if ( state.allRetrospectivesMap ) {
    return state.allRetrospectivesMap.sortBy((retro) => retro.get('date'))
  } else {
    return Map({})
  }
}
```

I want to sort it by descendent order, from the last date to the first date. How can I do this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`reverse()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/reverse) the results:

```
state.allRetrospectivesMap.sortBy((retro) => retro.get('date')).reverse()
```

Or you can use [`sort()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/sort) with a comparator:

```
state.allRetrospectivesMap.sort((a, b) => b.get('date') - a.get('data')) // or any other relevant comparison between the dates
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert this to a ternary operator? something like this:
export const allRetrospectivesOrderedMapSelector = (state) => {
  state.allRetrospectivesMap
  ? state.allRetrospectivesMap.sortBy((retro) => retro.get('date')).reverse()
  : Map({})
}

Comment: `export const allRetrospectivesOrderedMapSelector = (state) =>  state.allRetrospectivesMap ? state.allRetrospectivesMap.sortBy((retro) => retro.get('date')).reverse() : Map({})` - you don't need the outer curly brackets,